# How to remove the echoChar (TextField)?

Tags: passwords, awt, textfield

I'm using

```
setEchoChar('*');
```

on an AWT TextField for passwords. However, I can't find a way to undo this. The JavaDoc says I got to set echoChar to 0, but how do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Please confirm.

```
field.setEchoChar((char)0);
```

Comment: Working! Thanks! But why does setEchoChar('0') not work? (as it should do the same as (char)0 right?)

Comment: NO. '0' is not the same. Ascii/Unicode for '0' is 48 and 0 is well 0.